# Complex analysis, logarithmic residue

Tags: complex-analysis

Why it is true , that the logarithmic residue of function at isolated singularity point always integer number?

Comment: More needs to be asked of the function for the 'logarithmic residue' to be defined at an isolated essential singularity. For a pole $z_0$ of order $m$ you can write the function as $f(z)=(z-z_0)^{-m}h(z)$ for $h$ analytic with $h(z_0)\neq0$. Then $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{-m(z-z_0)^{-m-1}h(z)+(z-z_0)^{-m}h'(z)}{(z-z_0)^{-m}h(z)}=\frac{-m}{z-z_0}+\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}$. Integrating, and taking into account that $h(z_0)\neq0$ and therefore $\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}$ is analytic near $z_0$, you get that the integral is $-m$.

Comment: The residue is an integer [because it's a winding number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626656/not-an-essential-singularity). (If the point is an isolated singularity of $f'/f$.)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1197698/42969) is a  nice (analytical) argument why the winding number is always an integer.

Comment: @egorovik , And what about essential singularities?

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO The 'logarithmic residue' may not be defined at all, or be infinite.